# How to log(debug) javaagent with agent options

Tags: java, debugging, logging, javaagents

I set up my javaagent in the like this:

```
-javaagent:/usr/pkg/tomcat/lib/aspectjweaver-1.7.3.jar
```

But it does not work, so I would be interested to have a look at the logs. What can I add to javaagent if I want to get log messages? (stacktrace, which classes were loaded etc...)

I beleive "options" should be used for this.

The documentation says:

*implementations with a command-line interface, an agent is started by adding this option to the command-line:*

```
-javaagent:jarpath[=options]
```

*jarpath is the path to the agent JAR file. options is the agent options*

What **exactly** should I write within the square brackets? "Log"? "Debug"? Something else?
I know its lame but I can't find the correct syntax.

Answer (score 1):

this needs to be added

```
-Daj.weaving.verbose=true
```