# -javaagent option parameter for web application

Tags: java, performance, web-applications, weblogic, monitoring

I'm trying to use `Instrumentation` for calculating the memory use by several objects in a web application (on a request basis, to be precise).

Unfortunately it seems WebLogic does not plug into static void `premain` or `agentmain`.

For completion's sake here is the Intrumentation instantiation class:

```
public class InstrumentationInstance {
    private static Instrumentation instrumentation;

    public static void premain(String args, Instrumentation ins){
        instrumentation = ins;
    }
    public static void agentmain(String args, Instrumentation ins){
        instrumentation = ins;
    }

    public static Instrumentation instrumentation(){
        return instrumentation;
    }
}
```

I've tried adding these to the manifest but `Instrumentation` is still null:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Premain-Class: com.things.monitoring.InstrumentationInstance
Agent-Class: com.things.monitoring.InstrumentationInstance
Class-Path:
```

Reading it looks like this application would need to be launched with the java option `-javaagent` so that the `premain` and `agentmain` methods would be noticed. I THINK this would be done in the `web.xml`/`weblogic.xml` file? But I can't seem to find any examples or evidence pointing to how...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options:

- Add `-javaagent` to your `startWebLogic.sh` script in the `JAVA_OPTIONS` section. Note that this will apply to all servers
- Add `-javaagent` to your server start arguments in the admin console. Navigate to `Servers -> Server Name -> Configuration -> Server Start tab` and edit the `Arguments` section. You can add other arguments here as well, memory args, -D args, etc.

This [link](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/java-agent/frameworks/weblogic-installation-java) also covers it pretty well. I do not think this is something you should put in your weblogic.xml file.

Comment: I set arguments in the server in console. However it doesn't seem to run `premain`, `agentmain`, and WebLogic is not giving me any sort of acknowledgement or errors in the console

Comment: Have you tried turning up debug like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21733303/how-to-logdebug-javaagent-with-agent-options ?

Comment: it worked with the `JAVA_OPTIONS ` method (kind of, now it's saying it can't find the `Premain-Class`, but hey we're close!). The verbose setting didn't do anything.

Comment: Ok good - if you find out more info you would like to share, feel free to edit your question or my answer with the details